# Is this algorithm analysis correct

Tags: algorithm

I am reading the Algorithm Design Manual and this solution is not in the manual. I spent a solid 30 minutes figuring it out so I was wondering if it is correct. Here is the pseudocode for the function :

```
function conundrum(n)
  r:=0
  for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=i+1 to n do
      for k:=i+j−1 to n do
        r:=r+1
```

[image]

we solve the first summation and we get

[image]

[image]

the final equations should be :

[image]

Given that the n^4 is negative we can conclude that the running time of this algorithm is [image]

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end result is correct, there is at least one error in the detailed calculation: a sum from a to b over 1 is b-a+1.

Also, the sign of the next term is irrelevant (I assume you meant n^2). The runtime would be Theta(n^3) even when the n^2 term is positive.

Comment: after a second look I see that I mistook the 2n for 2n^2 and this is why I got n^4. about the sum thing, can you point out the error ?

Comment: I thought I did that: if you sum 1 with bounds from a to b, the result is b-a+1 and not just b-a.